# How to format "links" in jqgrid in single words?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have an entire column of links that are retrieved from the database like this:

```
https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=www.amada-book.com/uploads/1369072920.zip
```

How do I get to show like html tag on the column in my grid?
Like this:

```
< a href=" https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=www.amada-book.com/uploads/1369072920.zip">FILES </a>
```

So the only word you see is "FILES" but a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter) in your column model

Ex

```
colModel: [ 
    {
        name:'price', 
        index:'price', 
        width:60, 
        align:"center", 
        editable: true, 
        formatter:function(cellvalue, options, rowObject){
            return '<a href="' + cellvalue + '">FILES </a> '
        }
    },
]
```

Comment: This answer looks like it's what I'm looking for only that it displays like this: <a href="https://docs.google.com /viewer?url=localhost/media- management/uploads /1369719219.zip">FILES

Comment: @Oleg can I get some advice on this delete button problem please? [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823935/how-to-add-a-second-custom-delete-button-on-navbar-jqgrid)

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
var myvalue = https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=www.amada-book.com/uploads/1369072920.zip;
```

your grid value will be like   `"<a href=" + myvalue  + ">Files</a>";`

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe create an event to achieve what happens after you click the column:

```
$("#gridColumn").click(
  function() {
      location.href= "https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=www.amada-book.com/uploads/1369072920.zip";
     //or this 
     window.open("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=www.amada-book.com/uploads/1369072920.zip");
  }
);
```